# SAS SQL Pass-Through Facility does not work as expected for Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, sas, data-integration, pass-through

I am working with SCD Type 2 transformation in SAS Data integration Studio (4.905) and using Postgres (12) as database.

I am facing the following error when I try to execute a query via passthrough:

[image]

When using passthrough in Postgres, SCD Type 2 doesn't enclose the table name in quotes (which would keep the name uppercase, since postgres converts all unquoted data to lowercase) and so doesn't find it as you can see.

My questions are:

Is there a way to make SCD2 transformation declare the table’s name, used via passthrough, in quotes?

Is there a way to make the SCD2 transformation create intermediate tables ‘name in lower case so that the reference is not lost when doing passthrough?

Is there a global option in DI that allow us to modify/edit temporary table names?

Source and target tables are postgresql tables, with name and columns name in lowercase:
[image]

Please, if anyone has faced this problem before or knows what is missing, please, let I know.

Comment: You'll get a faster answer for DI questions on communities.sas.com

Comment: Not always. _(moreover, communities.sas.com too much organized as a chat box, too little as a knowledge base)_

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, we have to select the following highlighted (source and target) table options. 
 It results in quotes around source/target table names:

[image]

[image]

Then, SCD2 transformation automatically put quotes in tables y columns names as you can see:

[image]